# attach image to my input type browse button in mvc3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i want to attach image of browse button to my input type = "file"

```
<input type="file" name="browse1" value="browse1">
```

the image is lying in one of my project folder

how to attach it please help

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=file]::before{
content: url(imagepath);
}
```

this gets all input elements with "file" in the type-attribute. before says that the following content should be attached before the elements. And content attaches the image.

Comment: it's a css. Either in the head `<style type="text/css">code</style>` or in an external file and then... `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="filepath">`

Comment: sorry, my fault. I didn't expect that this doesn't work on inputs. could it be that you'd like to have an own upload-button? If you try to do this... let me say... you'll have a lot of fun. You can't change the button because of security issues.

Comment: yup....but there should be some way that we can change the look and feel of the browse button in the inpu type = file